# Append element to table using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have one empty div:

```
<div id="productlist" class="productlist" style="float:left;"> </div>
```

I appended the table in  :

```
$parent = $("#productlist").empty();
$parent.append('<table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="productlist"><tbody>');
```

In the  I tried to add the row and the column in it :

```
$("#myTable > tbody").append('<br />');
$("#myTable > tbody").append('<tr align="center"><td align="center" id="colunm-product"><div id="brand-item"><a href="#" class="brand_id">Image here.</a></div>');
$("#myTable > tbody").append('<div class="newproduct" id="newproduct"><a href="#">New product.</a></div>');
$("#myTable > tbody").append('<div id="product_image"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">My image</a></div>');
$("#myTable > tbody").append('</td></tr></table>');
```

But the result in my view :

```
 <table id="myTable" class="productlist" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-left: 4px; padding-top: 2px;">
  <tbody>
    <br />
    <tr align="center">
       <td align="center" id="colunm-product">
           <div id="brand-item">
             <a href="#" class="brand_id">
                Image here.
             </a>
           </div>
       </td></tr>

       <div class="newproduct" id="newproduct"><a href="#">New product.</a></div>
       <div id="product_image"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">My image</a>
       </div>
 </table>
```

There's only one div in td. What about the others 2 div, Why they are not in that td? Could anyone tell me , how could I do that?

Thanks you.

Comment: As an aside, it may not be useful for your entire application, but for limited scenarios like this, KnockoutJS rocks. You basically manage a collection of source objects as a javascript object and the KnockoutJS handles all of the plumbing of keeping the HTML container populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample:http://jsfiddle.net/Q2WzA/

```
$parent = $("#productlist").html('');
$parent.append('<table id="myTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" class="productlist"><tbody>');



var $table = $parent.find("#myTable > tbody");



var htmlRow = [
    '<tr align="center">',
     '<td align="center" id="colunm-product">',
      '<div id="brand-item"><a href="#" class="brand_id">Image here.</a></div>',
      '<div class="newproduct" id="newproduct"><a href="#">New product.</a></div>',
      '<div id="product_image"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">My image</a></div>',
     '</td>',
    '</tr>'];

$table.append(htmlRow.join(''));​
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are actually appending the divs to the tbody element, not to the td.

You might want to create a td element, adding the divs to the td and then adding the td to the  tbody.

```
$("#myTable > tbody").append('<br />');
var td  = $("<td align="center" id="colunm-product"></td>");
td.append("<div id="brand-item"><a href="#" class="brand_id">Image here.</a></div>");
td.append('<div class="newproduct" id="newproduct"><a href="#">New product.</a></div>');
td.append('<div id="product_image"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">My image</a></div>');
var tr = $('<tr align="center"></tr>');
tr.append(td);
$("#myTable > tbody").append(tr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not call `append` method multiple times. Store the string in a variable and call it only once

```
 var strRow='<tr align="center"><td align="center" id="colunm-product"><div id="brand-item"><a href="#" class="brand_id">Image here.</a></div>';
 strRow+='<div class="newproduct" id="newproduct"><a href="#">New product.</a></div>';
 strRow+='<div id="product_image"><a href="#" style="text-decoration:none">My image</a></div>';
 strRow+='</td></tr>';
 $("#myTable > tbody").append(strRow);
```

Sample : http://jsfiddle.net/srrht/6/